# How to repeat a section in Google Forms before submit?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, repeat, google-forms

I'm new here and also new in Google Apps Script. I'm trying to find out how to repeat a section in Google Forms n times and the closest script I found is this one: [link](https://productforums.google.com/d/msg/docs/AQfNxohwKLM/CBr6wHTIVL4J)

But this script is usable in Edit mode, and I need a specific section repeats while someone is responding and how responses will be plotted in Google Spreadheet this way. Can someone help me?

Sorry for my English.

Comment: Please add an example of what code you have already tried.

Answer (score 0):

Google Apps Script can't edit the form response view while a respondent is viewing it.

To repeat a section, the form owner or editors should duplicate the section the number of times that it's required before sharing the form with respondents.

Related Questions

- [How to build a decision support app with Google Apps Script (forms with subquestions)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19760361/1595451)
- [refresh google form item list onOpen](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40512570/1595451)

Reference

- [Forms Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/)